# Trying to set $data['stuff'] in MY_Controller in Codeigniter receive Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.. why?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to set profile div box in MY_Controller based on whether the user is logged in or not.

If I can do this in a controller

```
$data['name']  = $name;
```

.. then why does this give me "Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" ?

```
    if($this->session->userdata('loggedInStatus') == "TRUE"){
        $data['profileDivFirstName'] = $this->session->userdata('first_name');
        $data['profileDivPicture'] = $this->session->userdata('picture');
        $this->load->vars( $data );
    }else{
        $data['profileDivInfoFirstName'] = "Anonymous User";
        $data['profileDivInfoPicture'] = "/assets/css/img/ico-unknown-user.gif";
        $this->load->vars( $data );
    }
```

Comment: Which line is it throwing the error on? Nothing in what you've posted should be throwing that error.

Comment: Continue. The error is on the part which you didn't give. Specially on loading the view as i am guessing.

Comment: pretty clear that the code you have showed here is not the one generating the errors. What does the error give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already instantiated `$data` which is an object. Since you're in MY_Controller, it is likely you made it. The code you posted doesn't show us much, but this:

```
$data['name']  = $name;
```

Won't work if `$data` is an object because an object expects you to use this format:

```
$data->name  = $name;
```

That will (or should, anyway) work, but you should look over your code to make sure you're not using that in something else, too.

Comment: This was exactly it.  I had been using $data as an array previously, but then made it an object in a hazy late night session and completely forgot.  Silly mistake.  thx!

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you are trying to use an OBJECT (class) as an ARRAY. This cannot be done.